# How do you log in when you first start the new install?

Tags: login, password

How do you sign in?  Ubuntu 11.10:  I've installed it twice and the first time it wouldn't recognize my password; the second time there's no "login" button or anything to start the whole process going.  Works in guest mode but I want to install other programs.

So please help a new user: How do you log in. And is there anyway to rescue a fresh install, if it won't accept your password, that you just created.

Comment: Check whether your Numlock key is enabled (or disabled). If it was enabled during installation, you need to enable it after installation as well. The reverse also applies.

Comment: "it wouldn't recognize my password;" did you try with and without capslock on? :)

Answer (score 2):

First you select your username, and then once you've typed in your password, you hit enter and you get logged in.

I agree with your sentiments though on the login, that is a seriously flawed design with the new login.

Comment: Errrrg... What? Flawed?

Comment: I disagree about the design being in anyway flawed. That is the problem with expressing opinions - there will always be others who disagree.

Comment: @BrunoPereira What I failed to express fully was that the lack of a login button can be confusing for a new user. For all the efforts of the Ubuntu team to make linux easy for newcomers, a missing "log me in" button seems a bit of a jarring omission. But that's my view.

Comment: @grahammechanical That is completely fine with me. I completely respect your opinions. I think my problem was that I failed to give reasoning behind my opinions, and hence the (deserved) downvotes.